# Angularjs json array issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

In my HTML page I have a partial view that contains a list of numbers, I want when I click delete I delete the partial view and when I click add I add the partial view to my html with the last options select in my list .comment i can do it with ng-model to retrieve the last value select.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-left StyleList ">
    <div class="ListPlace">
        <select class="form-control">

            <option ng-repeat = "place in ListPlaces" ng-model="place.name"> {{place.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: how i can  use ng-model to  have the last valeur in options list

Comment: i have partial view contains a list  retrived from json via Rest Api, i want when i delete  and add the partial i keep the last value selected in the options

Comment: Its still vague,
You want to auto-select last selected value whenever you fetch ListPlaces from Server via Rest Api?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:I am here using ng-repeat using JSON value to showing state list

i - We should use value attribute instead of using ng-model of option tag.

ii - And We can use ng-disabled for disable option tag by assigning a true or false value to a variable in js. Example:(**ddlDisState)**

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
  <label>State Name List </label>
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="ddlState" ng-disabled="ddlDisState" >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="st in StateData" 
    value="{{st.stateID}}">{{st.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```